# How to manually serialize a resource to Json in Api-Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a custom operation that, once called, performs some more tasks than simply adding an entity.

The result of these operations is the creation of a new entity that is then persisted in the database.

Now, as a return value I'm currently using the IRI of the just created entity.

I generate the IRI using `\ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface`.

This approach works but has a drawback: in the frontend I have to issue a new call to retrieve the data of the just created entity.

To avoid this call, I'd like to simply return the entity in the JSON format, but I don't find a way to immediately serialize it to return it.

**In practice: I currently return simply the IRI of the entity: how can I return the fully serialized entity, according to its serialization configuration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your custom operation controller returns an instance (or a collection of instances) of an Api-Platform managed entity instead of a `Response`, the object will be automatically serialized with your desired serializer configuration (using the same serialization groups you've already defined, etc).

If you return instead an instance of `Response`, the `SerializeListener` will not serialize it and just return it unchanged. If not, it will serialize it. You can see it working [here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/bcf2a46307febf4cf7f0288e7eed2b7c8c23ab66/src/EventListener/SerializeListener.php#L61).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if you are just asking for the php-internal json-serialization:

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Which can be included in any Model-class by just implementing the JsonSerializable Interface. Just return an alternative structure, which will be serialized.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: This is not a solution for me: I don't have to use PHP functions; I need to use Api Platform to do this as it enriches the response with some additional data that I need in the frontend... Thank you for your reply, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `spl_object_hash()` or `spl_object_id()`, see `SplObjectStorage::getHash()`

Comment: This is not a solution for me: I don't have to use PHP functions; I need to use Api Platform to do this as it enriches the response with some additional data that I need in the frontend... Thank you for your reply, anyway.

Comment: @Aerendir value type is: `resource` or `object`? You set entity id as `autoincrement + 1` and update auto increment, but better insert empty records to get ids and garbage collector called by cron or trigger to remove unused records